# Is there a way to navigate to a particular screen from any screen after a specific time?

Tags: flutter

I want to navigate to a screen after 3 mins. Meaning User can be at any of the available screens but after 3 min he should be redirected to that specific screen.

I tried timer() method but it is not working.

Comment: Add your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using the timer widget you need to specify the duration.
for the best result, you need to use it in initstate function.

`Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () { Navigator.of(context).pop(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home())); });`